# c# HTTP POST -- need to track post/upload progress

Tags: c#, http, post

My code works fine to POST a file to a pre-signed Amazon S3 url.
  However, I want to track the progress of the POST/upload for large files.  Is there an easy way to add this to my code?  How would I do that?
I don't need a progress bar, just an output to the console with the percentage of the file transfer that is complete such as:

1
2
3
etc

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(PUT_URL_FINAL[0]);
//PUT_URL_FINAL IS THE PRE-SIGNED AMAZON S3 URL THAT I AM SENDING THE FILE TO

request.Timeout = 360000; //6 minutes

request.Method = "PUT";

//result3 is the filename that I am sending                                     
request.ContentType = MimeType(result3)

byte[] byteArray =
    File.ReadAllBytes(result3);

request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); 

dataStream.Close();

//This will return "OK" if successful.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("++ HttpWebResponse: " +
                  ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a WebClient's `UploadDataAsync()` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploaddataasync.aspx) and tie into its `UploadProgressChanged` [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged.aspx).

-- UPDATE: changed sample to use UploadDataAsync instead of UploadFileAsync

Slightly modified sample From the MSDN:

```
    public static void UploadDataInBackground (string address, byte[] data)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient ();
        Uri uri = new Uri(address);


        // Specify a progress notification handler.
        client.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressCallback);
        client.UploadDataAsync (uri, "POST", data);
        Console.WriteLine ("Data upload started.");
    }

private static void UploadProgressCallback(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
    Console.WriteLine("{0}    uploaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...", 
        (string)e.UserState, 
        e.BytesSent, 
        e.TotalBytesToSend,
        e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

Comment: I need to pass the content type (.ContentType) to S3 when I use their pre-signed URL or it will not let me post to S3.  Can I do that with this code?   If so, can you please modify the code to show me how?

Comment: I also need it to be synchronous instead of asynchronous.  Can I just use the "UploadData" method instead or will that not fire an event if I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Why does it need to be synchronous?

Comment: I need to do some processing after the file transfer is complete, but that processing depends on if the transfer was successful or not.

Comment: For content-type, yes you can set it.  try client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "YourCustomContentTypeGoesHere");

Comment: If you want to have a realtime progress bar, you can't use a synchronous method, since that would block until the upload is complete. If you want to do something when it's finished, you can subscribe to the WebClient.UploadFileCompleted event.

Comment: You can do post-upload code (success or fail) by tying into the WebClient.OnUploadDataCompleted event.  Check the parameter of type UploadDataCompletedEventArgs for the Error property being set.